# Styled components in React v5

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

i updated styled components from 4 to 5 version and there is a problem with tests:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'large' of undefined
```

My code is:

```
export const Title = styled(FormattedTypography).attrs(() => ({
  component: 'span',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  fontFamily: 'decorative',
  fontSize: 'display2',
}))`
  margin-bottom: ${(props) => props.theme.spacing.large};
  text-align: center;
`;
```

Was the syntax changes or something like this? I can't find any information.

Answer (score 1):

> NOTE
>   Note: The object-form .attrs({}) syntax that was deprecated in v4 is removed in v5. Use function-form attrs instead .attrs(props => ({})) (you should have been seeing console warnings to make this update ahead of time.) [Docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#what-do-i-need-to-do-to-migrate-to-v5)

**v5** syntax example:

```js
const Component = styled.div.attrs(props => ({
  style: { width: `${props.progress}%` }
}))`
  background-color: #f3a42d;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
`

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Component progress={70} >70% Progress Bar</Component>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<!-- only for SOF snippets -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/styled-components/4.3.2/styled-components.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

See more examples form styled-components [.attrs api](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#attrs)